# O que fazer quando recebo um erro do tipo bad_alloc?

Tags: c++

Antes da pergunta em questão vamos supor um cenário:

- Eu tenho um programa qualquer escrito em GTK+;
- O programa utiliza o **operator new** para alocar recursos; (não confundir com o **operator new (std::nothrow)**)

Em determinado ponto do programa necessito alocar um recurso, e utilizo o operador `new`. O operador `new`, caso não consiga alocar memória do *heap*, irá gerar uma `exception` do tipo `std::bad_alloc`.

---

Se não há mais memória disponível no *heap*, não vou poder desenhar nenhuma janela GTK+ para informar ao usuário do problema. Também não posso mais alocar nenhum outro recurso (porque o operador `new` já me informou da falta de memória com o `std::bad_alloc`).

1. Qual a melhor solução a ser adotada nesse momento?
2. Devo encerrar o programa silenciosamente e apenas logar o erro no
   `std::cerr`?
3. Quais outras soluções possíveis para este tipo de problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minha lista de opções é a seguinte:

1. Em situações cotidianas (não-críticas), abortar o programa por falta de memória é o que dá para fazer mesmo (de preferência gravando num log). Em celulares é isso mesmo que acontece. Se o sistema operacional fizer overcommiting (dizer que alocou com sucesso mas só alocar memória quando ela for realmente usada), não vai adiantar testar o retorno do malloc (em C) nem capturar a exceção do new (em C++) então você está ferrado mesmo.
2. Se sua aplicação tem um loop principal "à espera de comandos do usuário" (já que é uma aplicação com GTK+) e algumas operações com início e fim bem definidos que podem alocar muita memória, você poderia pegar a exceção no loop principal e avisar o usuário que a operação falhou. Provavelmente ao voltar ao loop principal você já deve ter alguma memória liberada (rodaram os destrutores). Você também pode avisar na mensagem que o programa pode ter se tornado instável e sugerir para o usuário reiniciá-lo.
3. Capturar o bad_alloc no loop principal pode ser útil se a falha de alocação tiver sido causada por outro erro, como requisitar -1 byte de memória, que quando convertido para unsigned dá um número gigante. Nesse caso o erro de alocação não indica que o sistema está sem memória e sim que faltou validar algum parâmetro no seu código, pois o programa não deveria requisitar essa quantidade colossal de memória.
4. Se o seu programa precisa rodar continuamente, considere criar um processo supervisor que reinicie o programa sempre que for detectado que ele terminou inesperadamente. O novo processo criado vai recomeçar num estado muito mais previsível do que um programa que tentou tratar uma exceção bad_alloc!
5. Para que o bad_alloc não ocorra de surpresa no meio de uma operação, você poderia pré-alocar bastante memória e trabalhar apenas dentro dela. Mas seja cuidadoso, pois o alocador do sistema talvez tenha algumas proteções de escrita/leitura fora da área alocada que você perderá se tentar implementar tudo manualmente (cof, OpenSSL, cof, Heartbleed, cof).
6. Para tratar o bad_alloc, você pode pré-alocar um espaço de memória e deixá-lo sem uso, liberando somente quando houver erro de alocação. Já ouvi chamarem esta técnica de "paraquedas".

Note que todas as opções (menos a primeira) são trabalhosas e dependem de como funciona o seu programa (interativo? operações em lotes? pode ser reiniciado e continuar de onde parou?). Será necessário simular as situações de falta de memória para garantir que o tratamento funciona corretamente, e cuidar com problemas específicos de certos sistemas operacionais, como overcommiting.

Se você está implementando uma linguagem, um banco de dados, ou algum servidor, essas medidas de segurança são superimportantes. Se você está implementando um clone do Flappy Bird, nem tanto...

Answer (score 0):

1. Em geral, encerra-se algum procedimento crítico que possa estar sendo realizado no momento. O problema é que durante o encerramento mais erros podem ser gerados no caso em que para encerrar algo, seja necessário alocar mais memória. Os erros podem variar entre segfaults ou silenciosos crashes da aplicação, e são especialmente complicados de serem lidados no caso de serem lançados por uma biblioteca que você não possui o código fonte.

Talvez, sua aplicação crie cache de algo (de um arquivo, por exemplo), e então esse cache pode ser liberado, permitindo que a aplicação inclusive continue executando. Mas casos assim são raros e variam de aplicação para aplicação.

2. Se não for possível liberar memória e recursos do sistema (descritores de arquivo, etc), provavelmente esta pode ser a única solução, pois pode ser que no momento de realizar o log, o sistema operacional tente alocar memória e então ele também caia em uma situação de `bad_alloc`, e neste caso sua aplicação será terminada à força.
3. Conforme discutido em *1.*, se sua aplicação cria caches ou pré-aloca recursos, pode ser possível liberar estes recursos e continuar executando normalmente a aplicação.

Este exemplo que dei sobre o cache é utilizado de maneira transparente pelo Sistema Operacional.

Quando por exemplo um arquivo é aberto e lido, ele é mantido em memória por um tempo indefinido. Suas alterações, é claro, são propagadas para a estrutura de armazenamento secundária após um período de tempo (veja a parâmetro `commit` do `EXT4` para mais informações).

Os dados do arquivo são então mantidos em memória até que esta se encontre cheia (veja observação abaixo). Então, o sistema operacional desaloca memória antes ocupada pelo cache de arquivos até que seja suficiente alocar para a aplicação a requisitando. Se quiser observar este comportamento, o programa `top`, além do arquivo `/proc/meminfo` são os métodos mais simples de se enxergar esta condição (`htop` não exibe os números, não sendo muito efetivo). O `Task Manager` do Windows também exibe estes dados, embora eu os ache um pouco menos intuitivos e o Windows seja um pouco mais agressivo no assunto que trato na *observação* abaixo.

**Observação:** Liberar a memória apenas quando um programa a necessita é uma operação custosa, e que pode degradar o desempenho da aplicação. Assim, o Sistema Operacional na verdade sempre mantém uma área de memória livre, permitindo que a memória seja mais rapidamente entregue a aplicação que a necessite. Após a entrega, o SO pode ou não remover dados do cache, mantendo sempre uma quantidade livre de memória pronta para alocação. Vale ressaltar que paginação de disco é o último caso a ser utilizado pelo SO (apesar do Windows novamente adorar fugir um pouco a esta regra).

Apenas para exemplificar, a minha máquina (Gentoo) possui 16GB de RAM e 8GB de swap. Estou usando 2.8GB em aplicações, 5GB de buffers, 6.8GB em caches (e 0GB de swap). Ou seja, apenas 1.4GB esta efetivamente livre da minha RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Se você supõe que vai faltar memória heap, você deve preparar tua aplicação para exigir mais espaço de heap, ao iniciar. É uma ação para mitigar a possibilidade de falta de memória.
Mas a melhor alternativa em caso de falha depende mesmo do propósito de tua aplicação.
Se for uma aplicação crítica de alto desempenho, você pode definir regras e parâmetros iniciais para garantir que uma determinada tarefa possa ser iniciada. Assim você pode alertar o usuário em caso de recursos não estarem atendendo plenamente a necessidade.
Com a avaliação constante dos recursos, você pode pausar a execução e com isto evitar erros críticos, informando o usuário da situação e meios de contornar o problema.
Não sei exatamente qual o propósito e forma de operar de seu projeto, mas sem dúvida o uso de cache é uma excelente alternativa para gerenciar recursos finitos.